# Xamarin Forms Maps Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maps, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get a simple Map working in Xamarin Forms. I alread succeeded for WinPhone, but Android is making it very difficult.
I've followed [this walkthrough](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/maps/) for getting an API key etc.. But when I add the NuGet package for Xamarin.Forms.Maps and updated all packages, I get the 5 errors including:

`Error:  error: package android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout does not exist`

I already tried the solution on [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/142825) (GooglePlayServices downgrade), but that's not working either.
I suspect it has something to do with faulty updates of the packages, but I don't want to blame the guys responsible for that.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Make sure you have GooglePlayServices installed on Android SDK, and all android sdks and build tools are updated.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me. My solution was to unload the project, reload it, tried again to download the nugets and the magic was done. Hope that solves your problem too.

**EDIT 08/10/2015**

Try searching this route: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Xamarin and see if there is any Android.Suppor.v7 folder, if not, that means xamarin did not downloaded the nuget, sometimes downloading them from xamarin studio solves the problem (it does not always works, but it's worth to give it a try).

If that does not work, other thing you can try is to go to your solution folder and delete the .package files, that will erase all the nugets, then you open the solution in vs or xs and restore the nugets.

Hope some of this tips helps you. Cheers